# preg_match case insensitive for registration

Tags: php, preg-match

Trying to validate a registration page, with it being case insensitive.

```
if(preg_match('[^a-z]', substr($username, 0, 1)))
        $errors['username']['start_type'] = ' Username must begin with a letter. Please try again.'; 

if(preg_match('[^a-z]', substr($username, 0, 1)))
        $errors['username']['start_type'] = ' Username must begin with a letter. Please try again.';
```

Comment: `'[^a-z]'` => `'/[^a-z]/'`

Comment: What is the question?